# Get List of all types of a certain string-type

Tags: typescript

I had this typescript generated by the generateTypeScript-gradle plugin.

```
export type FoodUnit = "AS_NEEDED" | "G" | "KG" | "ML" | "L" | "JAR" | "CAN" | "PIECE" | "BUNCH" | "HANDFUL" | "STALK" | "SLICE" | "TABLESPOON" | "TEASPOON" | "DROP" | "CUP" | "TWIG";
```

Now I want to have a list of all possible units in a class.

```
  units:FoodUnit[] = ["AS_NEEDED", "G", "KG" .....
```

Is there a way to instead write

```
  units:FoodUnit[] = FoodUnit.values()
```

like I would in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your generated code uses the `type` keyword and thus produces a [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases):

```
export type FoodUnit = "AS_NEEDED" | "G" | "KG" | "ML" | "L" | "JAR" | "CAN" | "PIECE" | "BUNCH" | "HANDFUL" | "STALK" | "SLICE" | "TABLESPOON" | "TEASPOON" | "DROP" | "CUP" | "TWIG";
```

Type aliases are purely compile-time constructs: they don't exist in any form in your JS code that is actually run by a browser or Node.

If you want a string-based enum construct, you can use a library like [typescript-string-enums](https://github.com/dphilipson/typescript-string-enums) or do it yourself [as documented here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/literal-types.html#string-based-enums).